# Constructor RecyclerViewAdapter in class RecyclerViewAdapter cannot be applied to given types

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, interface

I am trying to create onClickListener for my RecyclerView CardView items using interface method. I am new and according to my knowledge, you need to have constructors for the adapter class. I have created the constructors but I still receive the error. When I type "this" at "RecyclerViewAdapter myrvAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(NewCategory,this);", "mData" shows up instead of "onCardViewListener".

Error:

```
error: constructor RecyclerViewAdapter in class RecyclerViewAdapter cannot be applied to given types;
required: Context,List<Category>,OnCardViewListener
found: ActivityTwo,ActivityTwo,ActivityTwo,List<Category>
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

I have the following Java code in Android Studio:

RecyclerViewAdapter.java:

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

private Context mContext;
private List<Category> mData;
private OnCardViewListener mOnCardViewListener;

public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context mContext, List<Category> mData, OnCardViewListener onCardViewListener){
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.mData = mData;
    this.mOnCardViewListener = onCardViewListener;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view;
    LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.cardview_items_categories,parent,false);
    return new MyViewHolder(view, mOnCardViewListener);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.tv_category_title.setText(mData.get(position).getTitle());
    holder.img_category_icon.setImageResource(mData.get(position).getIcon());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mData.size();
}

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    TextView tv_category_title;
    ImageView img_category_icon;
    CardView cardView;
    OnCardViewListener mOnCardViewListener;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView, OnCardViewListener onCardViewListener){
        super(itemView);

        tv_category_title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.category_text);
        img_category_icon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.category_icon);
        cardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv_nav);
        mOnCardViewListener = onCardViewListener;

        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        mOnCardViewListener.onCardViewClick(getAdapterPosition());

    }
}

public interface OnCardViewListener{
    void onCardViewClick(int position);
}
```

ActivityTwo.java:

```
public class ActivityTwo extends AppCompatActivity implements RecyclerViewAdapter.OnCardViewListener {

private static final String TAG = "ActivityTwo";

private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

private ViewPager mViewPager;

List<Category> NewCategory;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_two);

    NewCategory = new ArrayList<>();
    NewCategory.add(new Category("Food & Beverages",R.drawable.fnb_24));
    NewCategory.add(new Category("Administration",R.drawable.admin_white_24dp));
    NewCategory.add(new Category("Faculty Blocks",R.drawable.faculty_white_24dp));
    NewCategory.add(new Category("Teaching Buildings",R.drawable.teaching_24));
    NewCategory.add(new Category("Library & Study Areas",R.drawable.library_white_24dp));
    NewCategory.add(new Category("Research Buildings",R.drawable.research_24));
    NewCategory.add(new Category("Campus Accommodations",R.drawable.accommt_white_24dp));
    NewCategory.add(new Category("Sports",R.drawable.sports_white_24dp));
    NewCategory.add(new Category("Student Association",R.drawable.sa_24dp));
    NewCategory.add(new Category("Information Services",R.drawable.it_white_24dp));
    NewCategory.add(new Category("Islamic Centre & Mosques",R.drawable.mosque_24));
    NewCategory.add(new Category("Guard Houses",R.drawable.security_24));

    RecyclerView myrv = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recylcerview_navigation);
    RecyclerViewAdapter myrvAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(NewCategory,this);
    myrv.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this,2));
    myrv.setAdapter(myrvAdapter);

    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.bottom_nav_bar);

    Menu menu = bottomNavigationView.getMenu();
    MenuItem menuItem = menu.getItem(2);
    menuItem.setChecked(true);

    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()){
                case R.id.timetable:
                    Intent intent0 = new Intent(ActivityTwo.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent0);
                    overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
                    break;

                case R.id.transports:
                    Intent intent1 = new Intent(ActivityTwo.this, ActivityOne.class);
                    startActivity(intent1);
                    overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
                    break;

                case R.id.navigation:
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

}

@Override
public void onCardViewClick(int position) {
}
```

Category.java:

```
public class Category {

private String title;
private  int icon;

public Category (){
}

public Category(String title, int icon) {
    this.title = title;
    this.icon = icon;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public int getIcon() {
    return icon;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public void setIcon(int icon) {
    this.icon = icon;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is pretty clear. Your constructor is expecting 3 parameters and you are passing only one.

Your constructor:

```
public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context mContext, List<Category> mData, OnCardViewListener onCardViewListener){
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.mData = mData;
    this.mOnCardViewListener = onCardViewListener;
}
```

You need to pass the data and the listener too, like this:

```
RecyclerViewAdapter myrvAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(NewCategory.this, data, this);
```

Also your NewCategory ArrayList is missing a name, so instead:

```
NewCategory = new ArrayList<>();
```

Change to:

```
List<NewCategory> data = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: Category.java:
```
public class Category {

    private String title;
    private  int icon;

    public Category (){
    }

    public Category(String title, int icon) {
        this.title = title;
        this.icon = icon;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public int getIcon() {
        return icon;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public void setIcon(int icon) {
        this.icon = icon;
    }
```
I followed your way and get error: cannot find symbol class NewCategory

Comment: Please refer to the edited post as I had added a new class showing where List<Category> NewCategory comes from. I followed your way of passing the parameters and get I get error: cannot find symbol class NewCategory

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem. Previously mContext is used for LayoutInflater. This caused the constructor to require 3 parameters, and I was getting errors as mContext is not defined in ActivityTwo.java. Thus, changing how I write the LayoutInflater code I managed to reduce the number of parameters to 2, and the code works fine. Hope this will help someone new to constructors and parameters.

Refer below on changes made:

```
View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cardview_items_categories, parent, false);
```

RecyclerViewAdapter.java:

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

private List<Category> mData;
private OnCardViewListener mOnCardViewListener;

public RecyclerViewAdapter(List<Category> mData, OnCardViewListener onCardViewListener){

    this.mData = mData;
    this.mOnCardViewListener = onCardViewListener;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cardview_items_categories, parent, false);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.tv_category_title.setText(mData.get(position).getTitle());
    holder.img_category_icon.setImageResource(mData.get(position).getIcon());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mData.size();
}

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    TextView tv_category_title;
    ImageView img_category_icon;
    CardView cardView;
    OnCardViewListener mOnCardViewListener;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView, OnCardViewListener onCardViewListener){
        super(itemView);

        tv_category_title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.category_text);
        img_category_icon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.category_icon);
        cardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv_nav);
        mOnCardViewListener = onCardViewListener;

        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        mOnCardViewListener.onCardViewClick(getAdapterPosition());

    }
}

public interface OnCardViewListener{
    void onCardViewClick(int position);
}
```

ActivityTwo.java:

```
public class ActivityTwo extends AppCompatActivity implements RecyclerViewAdapter.OnCardViewListener {

private static final String TAG = "ActivityTwo";

private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

private ViewPager mViewPager;

List<Category> NewCategory;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_two);

    NewCategory  = new ArrayList<>();
    NewCategory.add(new Category("Food & Beverages",R.drawable.fnb_24));
    NewCategory.add(new Category("Administration",R.drawable.admin_white_24dp));
    NewCategory.add(new Category("Faculty Blocks",R.drawable.faculty_white_24dp));
    NewCategory.add(new Category("Teaching Buildings",R.drawable.teaching_24));
    NewCategory.add(new Category("Library & Study Areas",R.drawable.library_white_24dp));
    NewCategory.add(new Category("Research Buildings",R.drawable.research_24));
    NewCategory.add(new Category("Campus Accommodations",R.drawable.accommt_white_24dp));
    NewCategory.add(new Category("Sports",R.drawable.sports_white_24dp));
    NewCategory.add(new Category("Student Association",R.drawable.sa_24dp));
    NewCategory.add(new Category("Information Services",R.drawable.it_white_24dp));
    NewCategory.add(new Category("Islamic Centre & Mosques",R.drawable.mosque_24));
    NewCategory.add(new Category("Guard Houses",R.drawable.security_24));

    RecyclerView myrv = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recylcerview_navigation);
    RecyclerViewAdapter myrvAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(NewCategory,this);
    myrv.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this,2));
    myrv.setAdapter(myrvAdapter);

    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.bottom_nav_bar);

    Menu menu = bottomNavigationView.getMenu();
    MenuItem menuItem = menu.getItem(2);
    menuItem.setChecked(true);

    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()){
                case R.id.timetable:
                    Intent intent0 = new Intent(ActivityTwo.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent0);
                    overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
                    break;

                case R.id.transports:
                    Intent intent1 = new Intent(ActivityTwo.this, ActivityOne.class);
                    startActivity(intent1);
                    overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
                    break;

                case R.id.navigation:
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

}

@Override
public void onCardViewClick(int position) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onCardViewClick: Clicked!" + position);
}
```